# Slow INSERTs and DELETEs with a default setup of PostgreSQL on Fedora 17

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, fedora

(I'll try to give a short rundown of what I'm trying achieve and then describe the problem I'm facing)

**THE GOAL**

Ok, so I'm doing a basic benchmark on statement execution times in PostgreSQL (via JDBC). The cases I'm currently testing are the following:

EXPERIMENT #1: Insert 5000 orders into the orders table. Store the absolute execution time for each INSERT and calculate the average. The SQL is something like:

```
INSERT INTO Order(order_ID, order_state_R_ID, customer_ID, submission_time, 
acceptance_time, completion_time, additional_info) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

EXPERIMENT #2: Select an order from the orders table for 5000 times. Store the absolute execution time for each of the SELECTs and calculate the average. So basically each of the rows that were inserted in the previous experiment are read in one-by-one to get a general idea of how long it would take. Corresponding SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Order WHERE order_ID = ?;
```

EXPERIMENT #3: Delete each of the orders that were inserted during experiment #1 (again, one-by-one). Store the absolute execution time for each DELETE and calculate the average.

```
DELETE FROM Order WHERE order_ID = ?;
```

**THE PROBLEM**

At first I ran these experiments on Windows 7 (with a default installation of PostgreSQL 9.2). The averages I got were something like: (#1: 1.5 ms), (#2: 0.4 ms), (#3: 1.9 ms).

Now, to get a better overview of the speed compared to another DBMS running exclusively on Linux, I rebuilt the whole environment in Fedora 17 (same PC, different logical partition) and ran the tests again. My problem is that for some odd reason the results are more like (#1: 15 ms), (#2: 0.2 ms), (#3: 15 ms) now. This means that the SELECTs are slightly faster but the INSERTs and DELETEs are miserably slow compared to that of Windows. The database is identical in both cases. Also, running ANALYZE or VACUUM FULL doesn't seem to be making any kind of difference.

I do realize that there are a lot of open ends here. However, I'd like to know if anybody has experienced a similar situation or has any tips in regards to where the bottle-neck might be?

To clarify: My goal is not to probe any kind of transaction throughput capabilities of PostgreSQL, put rather to find out the absolute execution times of the statements described above. Thus, every statement in every one of the experiments is executed serially and on one thread, using a single database connection.

Comment: What filesystems did you use?

Comment: @Jakub: Ext4 in Fedora, NTFS in Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A journaled filesystem like Ext4 can slow down pg since it's waiting for the data to be written to disk. See: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Reliable_Writes for more information. You can try turning off the synchronization using:

```
SET LOCAL synchronous_commit TO OFF;
```

Or changing the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is exactly what I was looking for! (PS - sorry for the delay, had to be AFK for a few hours) 
BTW - Is there a way to turn synchronous_commit off globally, as in for all sessions? I imagine that it would be better to do it individually in the transactions where it is needed, however I was just curious.

Comment: Also, what would be the most likely alternatives for Ext4 in such a case?

Comment: @PriiduNeemre I take it that worked then? Yes there are ways, either the configuration file or command line parameter: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html As for the second question, I'm afraid I don't know really. I know the problem but never had to solve it.

Comment: Holy crap the difference this makes when migrating a large database. Insane.